# Naming: createFunctionDelegate() vs createDelegateFunction()?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

It appears that I am not able to choose between two names for a function:

`createFunctionDelegate()` and `createDelegateFunction()`.

If it matters, the purpose of the function is that it creates a new function that calls the supplied callback function in the context of the second argument. For example:

```
var foo = {
    init: function() {
        setTimeout(App.createFunctionDelegate(this.method, this));
    },

    method: function() {}
}
```

When `foo.init()` is run, it sets a timeout that calls a function which delegates the execution to another function (`this.method`) called in the context of `this` (foo).

Anyway, I am not sure which way I should name this function. This is important to me, because I am going to use it in hundreds of places and sometimes I type the one and occasionally the other one. This has to change, I have to choose.

Comment: I wonder if it's wise to ask this question with this example as this is kind of meta-function. This is a very common problem that arises for every regular function, too, for example `decode_image()` or `image_decode()`, `calculate_date()` or `date_calculate()`?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard u like functions, so I made a function that returns a function so u can call while u call.

Comment: :D there are only two hard problems in computer science.  Cache invalidation, and naming things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use neither of these. What you want to do will be offered by [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in ES5. I would define `Function.prototype.bind` if it does not exist already, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) (but read the description and the possible drawbacks carfully).

This way you make sure you use native functionality if it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

What about just createDelegate(this.method, this)?

As a side note, other places where I've seen this kind of method (and written them), the param ordering is context, function, so createDelegate(this, this.method)